# What is the meaning of the set of Play Store icons at the top of the screen?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-nexus-10

Why are there a set of Google Play Store icons at the top of an Android (Nexus 10) screen?  What do they mean?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't have a screenshot, they are most likely apps that have recently been installed, updated, or have updates ready. I can give you more specific help if you post a screenshot.